# maven : getting dependency details (Equinox)

Tags: maven-2, equinox, pax

New to maven and equinox. While going through a tutorial on OSGi, I issued the following commmand.

**pax-provision**

which gave the following error.

```
 -> Provision bundle [mvn:org.compass-project/compass/2.1.1, at default start level, bundle will be started, bundle will
 be loaded from the cache]
 -> Preparing framework [Equinox 3.6.0]
 -> Downloading bundles...
 -> Equinox 3.6.0 : connecting...
         ___
        /  /
       /  / Oops, there has been a problem!
      /  /
     /__/   URL [mvn:org.eclipse.osgi/org.eclipse.osgi/3.6.0.v20100517] could not be resolved.
    ___
   /__/     Use --log=debug to see details.
```

Seems like the Equinox build is not available in the repository. So
1. Where to look for the repository which has the correct version. Is there any command or search tool??
2. I read, I may be able to install it locally, with the below command

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=<your_group_name>  \
-DartifactId=<your_artifact_name>  \
-Dversion=<snapshot>  \
-Dfile=<path_to_your_jar_file>  \
-Dpackaging=jar \
-DgeneratePom=true
```

How can I get all those parameters (group id, artifactId etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find 2 resource where I can get mvn packages. 
  http://mvnrepository.com/  and http://maven.ozacc.com/ . Please comment if this is the right place. I could get the artifact id etc from the search result. thanks